# Check which buttons are highlighted

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I am a beginner in C# trying to make a software and I am in the stage where I have to select seats(buttons) and add their name to the database. Following is code so far:

```
static int i;
int m = 0;// m is the maximum no of seats that can be selected.
public void seatSelector(Button btn) //Function To Change Seat Colour on Click
    {
        if (i < m && btn.BackColor == Color.Transparent)
        {
            btn.BackColor = Color.Green;
            i++;
        }
        else if (i <= m && btn.BackColor == Color.Green)
        {
            btn.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            i--;
        }
    }
//Lets assume I have total 4 seats(designed as buttons)
private void Seat1A_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        seatSelector(Seat1A);
    }
    private void Seat1B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        seatSelector(Seat1B);  
    }
    private void Seat1C_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        seatSelector(Seat1C);
    }
    private void Seat2D_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        seatSelector(Seat2D);
    }
```

My question is, how to extract the Name of the seats(Buttons) which are green in colour.Thank you

[image]

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: The best approach is having a List<Button> which you can enumerate. Store references to all buttons there! Then you can write a loop or use linq without ever writing code for single buttons. Btw: Even the code you have can be reduced to __one common__ click handler which casts `sender` to Button to know just which button was clicked..

Comment: I am sorry i did not know if I had ti mention that. It is windows form applications

Comment: It is helpful to see this in the questions page, so one can decide if one can or can't help..

Comment: Could you please help me with the pseudo code. I did not get what you are trying to say.

Comment: you have several options. easiest is to create a list and add or remove seats to/from it. another option is to loop through controls

Comment: `var seats = new List<Button>{Seat1A, Seat1B, Seat1C..};` then you can do `var greeSeats = seats.Where(x => x.BackColor == Color.Green).ToList();` - Also I suggest to define named colors like `Color booked = Color.Red; Color selected = Color.Green; Color free = Color.White`..

Comment: Btw, I don't understand what the _maximum no of seats that can be selected_ is supposed to mean or do..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have several ways to accomplish what you are looking to do.

One of my suggestions is to loop through your button controls and see which has been clicked.

```
//Loop through all controls


Foreach (Button s in Page.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        //Check button color
        IF (s.BackColor = Color.Green) Then
        { 
           //This Button is highlighted
           //do stuff;
        }
    }
```

Comment: if this help, feel free to +1  :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do

```
// in constructor
Seat1A.Click += seatSelector;
Seat1B.Click += seatSelector;
Seat1C.Click += seatSelector;
// etc.
//. . . . . . 
// !!! - What you need here is 3 states: unavailable, selected, unselected
// In the beginning you should fill unavailable

private List<string> _unavailable = new ...   //(fill this on form open from db)
// paint unavailable in [lets say] blue
private void PaintUnavailable()
{
    foreach (Control c in surface.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(Button) && _unavailable.Contains(c.Text)) 
        {
             c.BackColor = Color.Blue; // or ((Button)c).BackColor = Color.Blue
        }
    }
}


private List<string> _selected = new ...


private void SeatSelector(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = (Button)sender;

    if (!_unavailable.Contains(btn.Text))
    {
        if (btn.BackColor == Color.Transparent)
        {
            btn.BackColor = Color.Green;
            _selected.Add(btn.Text);
        }
        else if (BackColor == Color.Green)
        {
            btn.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            _selected.Remove(btn.Text);
        }
    }

}
```

then you can use "selected" for writing to db. This is just an example, unsophisticated sample of what generally needs to happen. `String/button.text` are not the best approach. You can have each button having specific object in `Tag` property, etc.